# Changing the math font in a presentation

Tags: math-mode, fonts, amsmath

I am currently using the Metropolis theme (https://github.com/matze/mtheme) to make a presentation. Since I didn't have the custom font used by this theme, I have changed to a different sans serif, from the theme's preferences.

I would like to use the default serif font used by latex in math mode for either a small part of the presentation (let's say within a paragraph) or better for all the equations which I am going to put. I have tried different solutions - see similar questions - but it seems to be working only for the greek letters which I have used in my equations. The normal letters still have the non-default sans serif font which I have used in the presentation.

Is there any way possible to achieve this result?

Comment: Have you create a MWE, please?